# Can't find executable file inside release-builds in Reactide

Tags: reactjs, ide

I tried to install react tide IDE and I did all the installation instruction

```
git checkout 3.0-release
npm install
npm run webpack-production
npm run electron-packager
```

but still there's no executable file
[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to run it in dev mode you can just type
`npm start` from the root directory.

If you havent got an exe try running the packager directly with

`npx electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --prune=true --out=release-builds`